# Inject variable from server for Axios in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to hide a URL from the user that tells the app which endpoint it should use.

In nuxt, I have 2 plugins:

```
[
  "~/endpoint.server.js",
  "~/api.js",
]
```

In `endpoint.server.js`, I'm fetch an endpoint for all subsequent requests to run on **if** my app in production. I don't want this URL (private.com below) to be public, hence running it on the server only.

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default async function ({ $axios, redirect, app }, inject) {
  // Set staging
  let staging = !!app.$env.STAGING;
  app.$staging = staging;
  inject('staging', staging);

  if(app.$staging){
    inject('baseURL', "https://staging-data.com");
  }else{
    // console.log("Setting custom endpoint");
    let { data } = await axios.get("http://private.com");
    inject('baseURL', data.endpoint);
  }
}
```

Note how I `inject` the $baseURL. Then, inside of api.js I have the following:

```
export default async function ({ $axios, redirect, app }, inject) {

  // Create a custom axios instance
  const api = $axios.create();


  // Set the base URL
  api.setBaseURL(app.$baseURL);

  // Inject to context as $api
  inject('api', api);
}
```

In all of my components I then use this special axios instance:

```
async asyncData({ $axios, route, app }) {
  const page = await app.$api.$get( "/" );
  return { page }
},
```

On first page load, this all works great. However, on subsequent page loads, the `$api` baseURL is set to `localhost` in the client.

I'm pretty sure in `endpoint.server.js` I'm correctly using the `combined inject` – https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/#combined-inject – how come my axios instance can't use the `baseURL`?

Answer (score 1):

Your plugin `endpoint.server.js` only runs on the server side. Which means, Axios is aware about those base url endpoints only on the server side.

When the plugin `api.js` runs on the client side, `app.$baseURL` is `undefined`. Because, `$baseURL` injection happens only on the server side via `endpoint.server.js`. You can verifiy this by going into your browser console and check if `$nuxt.$baseURL` is defined. It is definitely `undefined`.

The reason it works on the first load is that pretty much everything happens on the server side. So there are no Axios calls being made on the browser. But as soon as you start navigating on the browser, the SPA version of your app (client-side) starts executing and the client side Axios has no idea about your baseURLs. That's why it treats the `localhost` as your base url and things go wrong.

If you want to hide the API endpoint from the client side, then the approach you should take is probably a server middleware. Which is basically your API proxy. You call the [servermiddleware](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-servermiddleware/) from the Axios (e.g. /api/whatever) and the server middleware talks to your hidden API endpoint.

That should give you the result you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A better option would be to use an [axios proxy](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options.html#proxy) whose target value is set via ENV variables. In your nuxt config, you'd have something like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  axios: {
    proxy: true,
    prefix: '/api/'
  },

  proxy: {
    '/api/': {
      target: process.env.API_URL,
      pathRewrite: { '^/api/': '' }
    }
  },

  // etc.
}
```

Then, requests to `/api/foo` are forwarded to `http://private.com/foo` if your `API_URL` environment variable is `http://private.com/`.

However, this doesn't mean that that URL is hidden from the user, since your front-end code will still need to know how to make API requests. This is why you also need to use something like [JSON web tokens](http://jwt.io/) to ensure API requests are being done by a valid user.

Alternatively, you can run a lightweight server (e.g. Express) alongside Nuxt to forward API requests yourself so that the user can't see the API's actual URL. This wouldn't work for a static site, though, since you would need that server-side code running.